# How to determine whether a property defined in View Model is bound to any control in UI?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, properties

Is there a way to determine whether a property defined in View Model is bound to any controls in View, basically using Visual Studio.

Comment: At runtime or in the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can double-click on the property name to highlight it.  Then hit CTRL+SHIFT+F and select "Entire Solution" to see all occurrences.  And from there it's a process of manual inspection.

Alternatively, you can right click the property and select "Find usages", and begin the manual inspection from that point.  If you have ReSharper, you can access the advanced menu, which includes dynamic usages.

There are additional ways, but these are run-time.  The binding engine itself doesn't know until run-time, that's the beauty of binding.

Comment: @Garry....First option is what I mentioned as brute force. My requirement is to find those properties having binding relationship with controls in xaml file. "Find usages" only shows usages in C# file but not in xaml file. I do have Re-Sharper and would like to explore that. Any pointer to that.

Comment: @rajibdotnet, the current resharper should show xaml usages as well.

Answer (score 1):

With help of [Garry Vass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042344/garry-vass), I found how we can search for the usage of a property solution-wide. Great help.

Inside Visual Studio -> Right Click on a property - >
Find Usages Advanced(CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + F12) - > Search Properties - > Late-Bound references -> Find

Comment: I think in 8.2 they are calling it "Dynamic"

Comment: I am living in pre-historic age with Resharper version 5.1 :(

Answer (score 0):

The only option you have is "Find in file"

Since binding is done at runtime, the binding references are resolved by using (usually) Microsoft .NET Framework reflection. There is no validation done at compile time or with intellisense.

As such there is no way for the IDE to know what data context of the bound control would be, so impossible to find the references to it.

Comment: I did the same too, but its brute force. I believe there must be some elegant way to find it. This will help me clean up orphan properties. Thanks though Vincent.